# Address bar details isn't hidden when i set location no in the window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my application I'd like to display web page with addressbar details should be hidden. Hence I tried the below code and set location=no.

```
var strStyle  = 'status=yes,menubar=no,location=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,height='+strHeight+'px,width='+strWidth+'px,left='+strLeft+'px,top='+strTop+'px';
var newWindow = window.open(strFileName, strLaunchLocation, strStyle);
```

Unfortunatly It couldn't hidden the address bar which is visible to everyone. How do sort it out this issue ?

Comment: You can't. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7170997/921204

Comment: Perhaps try loading the page in an IFrame?

Comment: here you have a good answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170943/how-to-hide-javascript-window-open-address-bar-location-bar I think use a modal dialog with JQuery is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers doesn't hide address bar anymore.

Adding location=no to window.open will only make the address bar read only.